# python replace random line in large file

Tags: python

Assuming I ve got a large file where I want to replace nth line. I am aware of this solution:

```
w = open('out','w')
for line in open('in','r'):
    w.write(replace_somehow(line))

os.remove('in')
os.rename('out','in')
```

I do not want to rewrite the whole file with many lines if the line which is to be replaced in the beginning of the file.
Is there any proper possibility to replace nth line directly?

Comment: I believe you could use command line tools to do it http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html

Comment: The Problem is that command line tools do exactly the same: write a temporary file

Comment: @ProfHase85: Why is that a problem? It's the way pretty much everything works. There's a reason that we pretty much dropped the "random access files vs. sequential files" distinction back in the early 80s and only have sequential files nowadays.

Comment: Also, your sample code is opening different files for read and write, but your description is about replacing lines in-place within a file. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: You re right, forgot the last to lines I added now

Comment: @abarnert : The problem about this is that i am copying GB-wise data only to replace the 5th line of the file

Comment: @ProfHase85: The only _good_ answer is to store the data in a different format than a plain text file—a sequence of fixed-size records, a b-tree of extents, or whatever. (It depends on your other requirements.) A text file is, by definition, a sequence of variable-length records with no index, which means that you can't do what you want with it.

Comment: abarnert's answer is truly great. I will offer that Python makes it easy to write a temporary file and dispose of the original when finished. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15892338/353839 for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your new line is guaranteed to be exactly the same length as the original line, there is no way around rewriting the entire file.

---

Some word processors get really fancy by storing a journal of changes, or a big list of chunks with extra space at the end of each chunk, or a database of smaller chunks, so that auto-save modifications can be done quickly (just append to the journal, or rewrite a single chunk, or do a database update), but the real "save" button will then reconstruct the whole file and write it all at once.

This is worth doing if you autosave much more often than the user manually saves, and your files are very big. (Keep in mind that when, e.g., Microsoft Word was designed, 100KB was really big…)

---

And this points to the right answer. If you've got 5GB of data, and you need to change the Nth record within that, you should not be using a format that's defined as a sequence of variable-length records with no index. Which is what a text file is. The simplest format that makes sense for your case is a sequence of fixed-size records—but if you need to insert or remove records as well as changing them in-place, it will be just as bad as a text file would. So, first think through your requirements, then pick a data structure.

If you need to deal with some more limited format (like text files) for interchange with other programs, that's fine. You will have to rewrite the entire file once, after all of your changes, to "export", but you won't have to do it every time you make any change.

---

If all of your lines are exactly the same length, you can do this as follows:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(FIXED_LINE_LENGTH * line_number)
    f.write(new_line)
```

Note that it's length *in bytes* that matters, not length *in characters*. And you must open the file in binary mode to use it this way.

---

If you don't know which line number you're trying to replace, you'd want something like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        if is_the_right_line(line):
            f.seek(FIXED_LINE_LENGTH * line_number)
            f.write(new_line)
```

---

If your lines aren't all required to be the same length, but you can be absolutely positive that this one new line is the same length as the old line, you can do this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    last_pos = 0
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        if is_the_right_line(line):
            f.seek(last_pos)
            f.write(new_line)
        last_pos = f.tell()
```

Comment: @ProfHase85: For which version? And to accomplish what (or, rather, in place of which code)?

Comment: for the first version for example without needing the FIXED_LINE_LENGTH:

    with open('myfile.txt', 'rb+') as f:
        for i in range(line_number)
            f.readline()
        f.write(new_line)

Comment: @ProfHase85: Yeah, I guess you could… but it will be a lot slower for no real benefit, and also potentially confusing (because the file is a random-access collection of fixed-size records that happen to all end with newlines, but you're treating it as if it were a text file full of variable-length lines).

Comment: In all the solutions i do not understand why any line is replaced:
seek goes to any position of the file and f.write anything from there. If I use readline() I do the same without the restriction of fixed line lengths

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "i do not understand why any line is replaced"? In each case, we're seeking to the start of the line before doing the write. You can only do this if you know where the start of the line is. If lines are fixed length, and you know the line number in advance, you can just `seek`. If neither of those are true, you can't know which line you want until after you've already read it, which means you need to seek backward, which means you need to stash the `tell`. And so on. I can't think of any situation where what you're suggesting makes sense.